# Change table backcolor by FindControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dynamically creating tables based on entries in a DB. During this creation I assign one of the DB fields to the `Table.ID`. How can I change the backcolor of a table by using `FindControl(ID)`?

```
protected void AgentStat_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> activityAgent = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string conString = "Data Source = lewcomp1\\COMPLIANCE; Initial Catalog = 3CXCallStats; Integrated Security = True;";
    string query = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, Status FROM Queue_Listing WHERE [ComplianceCC(English)] = 'True'";
    SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myCon);
    SqlDataReader myReader;

    myCon.Open();
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        string name = myReader["FirstName"].ToString();
        string surname = myReader["LastName"].ToString();
        string status = myReader["Status"].ToString();
        activityAgent.Add(name + surname.Substring(0, 1), status);
    }


    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in activityAgent)
    {
        if (item.Value == "Connected")
        {
            var state = listAgents.FindControl(item.Key);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post HTML code for `ListAgents` ?

Comment: ListAgents is an empty div with the ID. Used as a container

Comment: Please have a look at my answer posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using var, I create and instance of the table and pointed it in the right direction. Please see below:

```
                TableCell tCell = (TableCell)listAgents.FindControl(item.Key);
                tCell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

If `item.key` contains the `ID` of the table which is marked as `Runat="Server"` then you can change background color of your table as mentioned below:

```
var myTable = listAgents.FindControl(item.Key) as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTable;
if(myTable != null)
{
    myTable.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor,  "Red");
}
```